# Orthogonal Projection Proof see if I did it correctly. Thanks

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help with a proof that I started.

so the question is to prove that $$\| \hat y \|^2 + \| y-\hat y \|^2 = \|y\|^2$$

where $\hat y$ is the orthogonal projection onto some subspace W. and the ||#||^2 defines the inner product of the number.

so I used properties of the inner product to get down to:

$$||y||^2 + 2\langle y,-\hat y\rangle = ||y||^2$$

where < y,-$\hat y$> is the inner product between y and -$\hat y$. 
So does this last inner product someone equate to 0 or did I screw up my proof. Is there another way to do it? Thank you.

Comment: I edited the first couple things for you to show you how it's done.

Comment: I don't know how you got your relation at the bottom (which is only true when $y$ is orthogonal to $W$), but there are $2$ tricks to solving this problem.  The first is to decompose $y$ into a sum of its projection and rejection from $W$: $y=\hat y + y_\bot$.  The second is to know that $\langle \hat y, y_\bot\rangle = 0$ (why?).  Can you see where to go from there?

Comment: Yeah I understand what you are doing it's just that in the way I am proving it, I separated the inner product $$\| y-\hat y \|^2$$ into $$\langle y,-\hat y, y-\hat y \rangle$$ and then used properties of inner product to simplify that down, do some cancellations, and I ended up with $$||y||^2 + 2\langle y,-\hat y\rangle = ||y||^2$$. So is my methodology correct? or am I blatantly wrong?

Comment: You must have made a mistake somewhere because that third line doesn't follow.  Give me a minute: I'll write up a solution.

Comment: As a total I ended up with that solution. So that solution includes the $$\| \hat y \|^2$$ that was given plus my breakdown of $$\| y-\hat y \|^2$$ and then the right side remained the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're trying to prove
$$\| \hat y \|^2 + \| y-\hat y \|^2 = \|y\|^2$$

The easiest way would just be to substitute $y=\hat y+y_\bot$ immediately, but let's wait until the end to do that so that you can see wherever you made a mistake:

$$\begin{align}\| \hat y \|^2 + \| y-\hat y \|^2 &= \langle \hat y, \hat y\rangle + \langle y-\hat y, y-\hat y\rangle \\ &= \langle \hat y, \hat y\rangle + \langle y, y-\hat y\rangle - \langle \hat y, y-\hat y\rangle \\ &= \langle \hat y, \hat y\rangle + \langle y, y\rangle - \langle y, \hat y\rangle - \langle \hat y, y\rangle - \left(-\langle \hat y, \hat y\rangle\right) \\ &= 2\langle \hat y, \hat y\rangle -2\langle y, \hat y\rangle +\langle y, y\rangle\end{align}$$

Here's what you should be getting.  Now we need to use that decomposition of $y$ into its projection and rejection from $W$:

$$\begin{align}\| \hat y \|^2 + \| y-\hat y \|^2 &= 2\langle \hat y, \hat y\rangle -2\langle y, \hat y\rangle +\langle y, y\rangle \\ &= 2\langle \hat y, \hat y\rangle -2\langle \hat y + y_\bot, \hat y\rangle +\langle y, y\rangle \\ &= 2\langle \hat y, \hat y\rangle -2\langle \hat y, \hat y\rangle -2\langle y_\bot, \hat y\rangle +\langle y, y\rangle \\ &= \langle y, y\rangle \\ &= \|y\|^2\end{align}$$

Note that I used $\langle y_\bot, \hat y\rangle = 0$.  Can you see why this is true?  I also assumed that this was a *real* inner product space so that $\langle a, b \rangle = \langle b, a\rangle$.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much! Did I do reasonably well getting to where I was :P